# Oozie co-ordinator actions rerun

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to rerun failed co-ordinators using below command but everytime it is restarting with some random co-ordinator action instead of oldest co-ordinator action first.

> oozie job -rerun {co-ordinator ID} -action 6374-6441

rerunning 6404 first. How can we make it rerun starting from 6374 first?

Comment: Please check: OOZIE-2766. Updated the answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this cannot be achieved at the moment by looking at this piece of code: [getActionsIds](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/coord/CoordUtils.java#L168)

```
    Set<String> actions = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] list = scope.split(",");
    for (String s : list) {
        s = s.trim();
        // An action range is specified with two actions separated by '-'
        if (s.contains("-")) {
            String[] range = s.split("-");
        ...............
            int start;
            int end;
            //Get the starting and ending action numbers
            try {
                start = Integer.parseInt(range[0].trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                throw new CommandException(ErrorCode.E0302, "could not parse " + range[0].trim() + "into an integer", ne);
            }
            try {
                end = Integer.parseInt(range[1].trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                throw new CommandException(ErrorCode.E0302, "could not parse " + range[1].trim() + "into an integer", ne);
            }
        ...............
            // Add the actionIds
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                actions.add(jobId + "@" + i);
            }
```

**Edit:** Here is the [Apache Jira OOZIE-2766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2766)  along with patch. Thanks.